# Functions Assist

Tags: python

I'm new to python and for an exercise I'm creating a function that would do the same as the .replace method.

I have this so far:

```
def replace_str (string, substring, replace):
    my_str = ""
    for index in range(len(string)):
        if string[index:index+len(substring)] == substring :
            my_str += replace
        else:
            my_str += string[index]   
    return my_str
```

When tested with:

```
print (replace_str("hello", "ell", "xx"))
```

It returns:

```
hxxllo
```

I was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction so that it replaces "ell" with "xx" and then skips to the "o" and prints:

```
hxxo
```

as the .replace string method would do.

Comment: These type of exercises are the worst.

Comment: Well if you can't import anything then regex is out.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, using a `while` with an index variable maintained by hand is a bad idea, but when you need to manipulate the index within the loop, it can be an okay option:

```
def replace_str(string, substring, replace):
    my_str = ""
    index = 0
    while index < len(string):
        if string[index:index+len(substring)] == substring:
            my_str += replace
            # advance index past the end of replaced part
        else:
            my_str += string[index]
            # advance index to the next character
    return my_str
```

Note that `x.replace(y, z)` does something different when `y` is empty. If you want to match that behavior, it may be worth a special case in your code.

Comment: It's advancing the index past the end of the replaced part that I can't figure out...

Comment: @user3321382: How long is the replaced part? Where does it start? Where does it end? Add enough to `index` to take it from where it is to where the replaced part ends.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
import sys

def replace_str(string, substring, replace):
    new_string = ''
    substr_idx = 0

    for character in string:
        if character == substring[substr_idx]:
            substr_idx += 1
        else:
            new_string += character
        if substr_idx == len(substring):
            new_string += replace
            substr_idx = 0
    return new_string

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage: %s [string] [substring] [replace]" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)
print(replace_str(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]))
```

Note that using the str.join() command on a list (list.append is O(1)) works faster than the above, but you said that you can't use the string methods.

Example usage:

```
$ python str.py hello ell pa
hpao
$ python str.py helloella ell pa
hpaopaa
```